# Neo4J Get Data From Multiple Node with Multiple Relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Hello Following My Neo4J Query to Get **CheckIn** or **Review** or **Pixel** etc. which is Given by User to Business.Which I got perfectly.but **I want also Get Pulse which given By User but not given on Business.** So My Following Query is not Get Pulse.

```
start n=node({otherUserId}) 
with n match (n)-[r1]-(p)-[r2]-(b:business) 
where r1.onPulse=true and r2.onPulse= true and 
('check_in' IN labels(p) OR 'tip' IN labels(p) OR 'review' IN labels(p) OR 'rate' IN labels(p)) 
with p,r1,r2,n,b 
optional match(p)-[r3:has_pix]-(pix:pix) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[tg]-(tags) 
where type(tg) in ['has_biz_tag', 'has_user_tag', 'has_hash_tag'] 
return n,r1,p,r2,r3
```

[image]

Above my Relationship node. I want Neo4J Query for that.

Comment: I do not understand properly, can you please explain a bit more.

Comment: I want to get **pulse** with **pixel** and **check_in**. Currently I got only **pixel** and **check_in**.

Comment: @MichaelHunger Please Help us to Solve above confusion. If you dont understand my question properly let me ask I will explain in Detail.

Comment: @Sadikhasan I think that you need to give an example of input data and the desired result - this will help to find a solution.

Comment: @stdob-- We need User Activity like **CheckIn**,**PixelPost**,**PulsePost** where **CheckIn** and **PixelPost** activity User do on Business but **PulsePost** activity user do not do on business.

Comment: @MichaelHunger We need User Activity like **CheckIn**,**PixelPost**,**PulsePost** where **CheckIn** and **PixelPost** activity User do on Business but **PulsePost** activity user do not do on business.

Comment: @cybersam Please Help us to Solve above confusion. If you dont understand my question properly let me ask I will explain in Detail

Comment: @Dave Bennett Please Help us to Solve above confusion. If you dont understand my question properly let me ask I will explain in Detail

Comment: You're not collecting any elements in the query, so you're going to get a cartesian product of all `check-in`, `tip`, `review`, and `rate`-related results (`r1`, `p`, `r2`) against all `pix`-related results (`r3`), along with pulse-related results once that's added to the query. That seems rather messy. It's also unclear what results you really need. You're returning relationships, and your `p` nodes, but you're not returning the `b` :Business node, or the `pix` :Pixel node, nor are you returning anything from your tag match, making it useless. Please clarify what you want returned and how.